# error when trying to deploy with nodejitsu

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, nodejitsu

I have a Windows 7 / 64bit machine and currenlty trying to deploy node.js based project to nodejitsu. But it do not works as expected and crash with error:

```
Executing command deploy
info:    Welcome to Nodejitsu yourapp
info:    jitsu v0.13.15, node v0.11.10
info:    It worked if it ends with Nodejitsu ok
warn:    You are using unstable version of node.js. You may experience problems.
info:    Executing command deploy

c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jitsu\lib\jitsu\package.js:248
      jitsu.log.warn(line);
                ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'warn' of undefined
    at c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jitsu\lib\jitsu\package.js:248:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jitsu\lib\jitsu\package.js:247:10
    at c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jitsu\node_modules\flatiron\node_modules\broadway
\node_modules\utile\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:94:25
    at checkProperty (c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jitsu\lib\jitsu\package.js:202:5)
    at c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jitsu\node_modules\flatiron\node_modules\broadway
\node_modules\utile\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:86:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _forEach (c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jitsu\node_modules\flatiron\node_module
s\broadway\node_modules\utile\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:26:24)
    at Object.async.forEach (c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jitsu\node_modules\flatiron
\node_modules\broadway\node_modules\utile\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:85:9)
    at Object.package.validate (c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jitsu\lib\jitsu\package.
js:205:9)
```

So what is the problem there and how it's possible to solve it?